# Would writing indexes in a suitable situation be better than a for-loop ONLY from a performance POV in c++?

Tags: c++, performance, compilation, compiler-optimization

Note: This question intends to check the code ONLY from a performance point of view, and not readability and scalability. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" they say, and in the example I've used, the potential performance benefits are VERY negligible. I am just wondering whether the compiler optimizations would result in the computer end up executing commands much like the one I wrote manually by just using the indexes and not using a for-loop.

Well, I had a very simple algorithm which would receive an array with the fixed size 10, from the user, and a number `n`, and it would print the number of occurrences of `n` in the given array. The algorithm was like this

```
int a[10] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
cin >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2] >> a[3] >> a[4] >> a[5] >> a[6] >> a[7] >> a[8] >> a[9];
int number;
cin >> number;
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (number == a[i]) {
        counter += 1;
    }
}
cout << counter << endl;
```

I was having a conversation with someone whether converting the line
`cin >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2] >> a[3] >> a[4] >> a[5] >> a[6] >> a[7] >> a[8] >> a[9];`  to a for-loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cin >> a[i];
}
```

would have a negative effect on the performance (only the performance, not readability, etc). My hypothesis is that in the for-loop, we are creating a variable `i` (and then modifying it, etc) and it would have very little negative effect (but still, a non-zero amount) on the performance.
Is my hypothesis true? Does it depend on the compiler? I could use time benchmarks for comparing the two, but the run time of the algorithm would be so low (around 300 nanoseconds) on my machine that I believe it is highly dependent on factors other than the algorithm itself (e.g. free memory, etc). What would be the ideal benchmarking procedure for such circumstances?

Comment: For 10 items, does it even matter? And depending on your `stdin`, you may be waiting on a user's extremely slow fingers for each of those 10 anyways. Is there some reason you want to optimize this? From what I can see, even if you manage to optimize perfectly, you won't actually see any notable difference.

Comment: @scohe001 That's very true. It does not matter. This was simply us thinking whether this would have `any` effect on the performance.

Comment: This is an optimization called loop unrolling and you compiler will do it better than you and you will still have nicer code.

Comment: As written and without optimization then the loop is doing a miniscule amount of more work of course, but it's not even worth noting.

Answer (score 3):

It's a very good thing that you're thinking of ways to make your code better and faster after already getting it working. I applaud you for that--it's something I wish some of my coworkers did more often :p

However, there is one hard and fast rule in the world of programming:

> Readability/maintainability trumps all.

I don't care how wicked fast and cool your code and algorithm are. If I can't read it and work with it, it means absolutely nothing to me. Not to mention--if you don't touch it for 3 months (which is a small amount of time in production code), you'll come back without any knowledge of what you've done.

All that to say, it makes me happy to see you trying to make your code faster, but the way you're trying to do it is by forcing the programmer to write out 10 different statements when they could just do one in a loop. What happens in the specs change and now you need to take 100 inputs? 1000? This is something that happens all the time in the real world!

This code is not maintainable or scalable.

So even if you could get *slightly* faster by unrolling the loop yourself (which is actually probably not true since modern compilers will do exactly that for you), I'd still say **don't do it!** Even if this has a slight impact on your runtime performance, it'll have a *far* bigger negative impact on future developer performance, which will eventually impact runtime performance.